# Undefined Symbol in inherited classes for member Functions C++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

So I'm writing a Manager class which inherits from SalariedEmployee which inherits from Employee. I have the employee.h header file and employee.cpp header file and also for salariedemployee as shown below.

I cant seem to understand why I get the following errors when I try to compile the code of

```
Undefined symbol: employeessavitch::SalariedEmployee::SalariedEmployee()
Undefined symbol: employeessavitch::SalariedEmployee::SalariedEmployee()
Undefined symbol: employeessavitch::SalariedEmployee::get_salary() const
Undefined symbol: employeessavitch::Employee::get_ssn() const
Undefined symbol: employeessavitch::Employee::get_name() const
```

Here are my files

employee.h

```
 #ifndef employee_h
#define employee_h

#include <string>
#include "employee.h"
using namespace std;

namespace employeessavitch
{

class Employee
{
    
public:
    Employee();
    Employee(string the_name, string the_ssn);
    string get_name( ) const;
    string get_ssn( ) const;
    double get_net_pay( ) const;
    void set_name(string new_name);
    void set_ssn(string new_ssn);
    void set_net_pay(double new_net_pay);
    void print_check( ) const;
    
    
protected:
    string name;
    string ssn;
    double net_pay;
    
};

}

#endif /* employee_h */
```

employee.cpp

```
    #include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "employee.h"
using namespace std;

namespace employeessavitch
{
    Employee::Employee(): name("No name yet"), ssn("No number yet"), net_pay(0)
    {
        //deliberately empty
    }

    Employee::Employee(string the_name, string the_ssn)
    {
        //deliberately empty
    }

    Employee::Employee(string the_name, string the_number): name(the_name), ssn(the_number), net_pay(0)
    {
        //deliberately empty
    }

    string Employee::get_name() const
    {
        return name;
    }

    string Employee::get_ssn() const
    {
        return ssn;
    }

    double Employee::get_net_pay() const
    {
        return net_pay;
    }

   void Employee::set_name(string new_name)
    {
        name = new_name;
    }
    void Employee::set_ssn(string new_ssn)
    {
        ssn = new_ssn;
    }

    void Employee::set_net_pay (double new_net_pay)
    {
        net_pay = new_net_pay;
    }

    void Employee::print_check( ) const
    {
        cout << "\nERROR: print_check FUNCTION CALLED FOR AN \n"
             << "UNDIFFERENTIATED EMPLOYEE. Aborting the program.\n"
             << "Check with the author of the program about this bug.\n";
        exit(1);
    }

}//employeessavitch
```

salariedemployee.h

```
 #ifndef salariedemployee_h
#define salariedemployee_h

#include <string>
#include "employee.h"
#include "salariedemployee.h"



namespace employeessavitch
{

    class SalariedEmployee : public Employee
    {
    public:
        SalariedEmployee();
        SalariedEmployee (string the_name, string the_ssn, double the_weekly_salary);
        double get_salary() const;
        void set_salary(double new_salary);
        void print_check();
    protected:
        double salary;//weekly
    };

}//employeessavitch


#endif /* salariedemployee_h */
```

salariedemployee.cpp

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "salariedemployee.h"

using namespace std;

namespace employeessavitch
{
   
    SalariedEmployee::SalariedEmployee() //: Employee(), salary(0)
    {
        //deliberately empty
    }
    SalariedEmployee::SalariedEmployee(string the_name, string the_number, double the_weekly_salary)//: Employee(the_name, the_number), salary(the_weekly_salary)
    {
        //deliberately empty
    }

    double SalariedEmployee::get_salary() const
    {
        return salary;
    }

    void SalariedEmployee::set_salary(double new_salary)
    {
        salary = new_salary;
    }
    void SalariedEmployee::print_check()
    {

        set_net_pay(salary);
        cout << "\n__________________________________________________\n";
        cout << "Pay to the order of " << get_name( ) << endl;
        cout << "The sum of " << get_net_pay( ) << " Dollars\n";
        cout << "_________________________________________________\n";
        cout << "Check Stub NOT NEGOTIABLE \n";

    void SalariedEmployee::print_check()
    {
        set_net_pay(salary);
        cout << "\n__________________________________________________\n";
        cout << "Pay to the order of " << get_name( ) << endl;
        cout << "The sum of " << get_net_pay( ) << " Dollars\n";
        cout << "_________________________________________________\n";
        cout << "Check Stub NOT NEGOTIABLE \n";
        cout << "Employee Number: " << get_ssn( ) << endl;
        cout << "Salaried Employee. Regular Pay: "
             << salary << endl;
        cout << "_________________________________________________\n";
    }
}//employeessavitch
```

main.cpp

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include "salariedemployee.h"
#include "employee.h"


using namespace std;

namespace employeessavitch
{
    class Manager: public SalariedEmployee
    {
    public:
        Manager();
        ~Manager();
        void addReport(SalariedEmployee employee);
        
        friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &outs, Manager manager);
    private:
        SalariedEmployee *reports;
        int noReport;
    };



    Manager::Manager()
    {
        noReport = 0;
    }
    Manager::~Manager()
    {
        delete[] reports;
    }


    void Manager::addReport(SalariedEmployee employee)
    {
        SalariedEmployee *report = new SalariedEmployee[noReport+1];
        for(int i = 0; i < noReport; i++)
        {
            report[i] = reports[i];
        }
        report[noReport+1] = employee;
        delete[] reports;
    }


    ostream& operator <<(ostream &outs, Manager manager)
    {
       
        for(int i = 0; i < manager.noReport; i++)
        {
            outs << manager.reports[i].get_name() << endl;
            outs << manager.reports[i].get_ssn() << endl;
            outs << manager.reports[i].get_salary() << endl;
        }
        return outs;
    }

}




int main()
{
    cout << "hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look like you are not linking all the files.

Comment: Recommendation: Back up your code and then take a hacksaw to it, removing stuff until you're down to exactly one problem (because all of the problems are probably the same thing with different names) and then keep hacking until the error goes away. The mistake is probably in the last chunk hacked off, so examine it more closely. Use [mre] as inspiration.

Comment: `void SalariedEmployee::print_check()` is missing its close brace. Odds are good Richard's right with the added bonus that the file's also probably not being compiled. You'd get different error messages if it was.

Comment: You also seem to have two `print_check` implementations, so maybe what you've got is a pasting error in the question. No way to tell for sure. Please correct.